# iOS:How to check if an directory already exists on the FTP server while uploading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

I am working on an App, in which I want to upload images and pdf to the FTP server. I am using this reference [ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt-DontLinkElementID_16).All is working good. The images and pdf are getting uploaded on the server with proper names and sizes.

But, now I want to check if the directory is already exists on the server or not. I am not able to get it to work with this library.

So my question is that how to check directory on ftp,if directory is there then upload the files if not then first create directory on ftp and then upload files onto that directory?

Any Ideas.. ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can anyone help me out for this issue?

Comment: Hey Vishal, consider my answer - or take inspiration from it to better define your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Different FTP servers will answer the `LIST` request in differing ways, so there is no single answer to this question. [RFC959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) says on the matter:

```
Since the information on a file may vary widely from system
to system, this information may be hard to use automatically
in a program, but may be quite useful to a human user.
```

Using the `CWD` request to change into the directory in question, and detecting a successful response will detect the directory, however that leaves you **in** that directory as a potentially unrequired side effect.

For these reasons, as well as others, you may find more modern protocols such as SSH (which includes a file transfer feature) to be more useful. You may find the [DLSFTPClient](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DLSFTPClient) CocoaPod useful.

M.